# How to toggle a radio button on and off using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

Hello I have a radio button I need to be able to toggle on and off. I know I should use a checkbox but unfortunately I am constrained to use radio buttons for reasons that would be too long to explain.

Its a single radio button so when I click on it, theres no way to turn it off.

Is it possible to toggle a single radio button on and off using jQuery?

This is what I have so far, but I cant get it to work.

```
    jQuery('.gfield_radio li input').click(function() {
        if(jQuery(this).is(':checked')) {
            jQuery(this).prop('checked', true);
        }

        else if (!jQuery(this).is(':checked')) {
            jQuery(this).prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Not a direct answer, but does it have to *be* a radio button, or just *look like* a radio button? You can use CSS to style a checkbox so it looks like a radio button (`appearance: radio`), if that helps. Not sure what the browser support is for it these days.

Comment: thanks for your answer, unfortunately i need to use a radio button

Comment: I personally would love to hear these "reasons that would be too long to explain"

Comment: i am using a wordpress plugin called gravity forms, and my work has a specialized plugin that works with gravity forms that was specifically created for us and for what we do. some reason checkboxes dont work with our plugin but radio boxes work @CrayonViolent

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wouldn't personally use a radio button. Anyway the code below is gonna work.

```
    var radioState;

    $('.my-radio').on('click', function() {
        if (radioState === this) {
            this.checked = false;
            radioState = null;
        } else {
            radioState = this;
        }
    });
```

jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/n76uvo00/

Comment: The best answer to this question on the web. Bravo!

Comment: @ZeljkoMiloradovic Thank you